# cuda copy to shared memory an array larger than thread count

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu-shared-memory

How would someone copy an array of a size x , if a kernel needs to have y threads for some other reason. All the examples I found are copying array of the size of thread count, such as:

```
__global__ void staticReverse(int *d, int n)
{
  __shared__ int s[64];
  int t = threadIdx.x;

  s[t] = d[t];
  __syncthreads();
```

1. How would it look If I need my `s[100000]` and I need to launch my kernel with just 1 block of 640 threads?
2. How would it look If I need my `s[100000]` and I need to launch my kernel with  10 blocks of 64 threads? Here I am also confused as a shared memory is just for 1 block, so I don't understand how threads from other blocks copy to shared memory of which block ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would it look If I need my s[100000] and I need to launch my kernel with just 1 block of 640 threads?

It wouldn't. Currently supported CUDA hardware has a [limit](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#compute-capabilities) of either 48kb or 96kb per block, so an integer shared array with 100000 elements is illegal.

But in general, if you had a design pattern where it was necessary to load more then one data point per thread into shared memory, then you would do something like this

```
__global__ void staticReverse(int *d, int n)
{
  __shared__ int s[2048];
  int t = threadIdx.x;

  for(; t < 2048; t += blockDim.x) s[t] = d[t];
  __syncthreads();
```

Because shared memory is strictly block scope, you *must* use something like the above design pattern to load data to shared storage. Obviously threads from other blocks can never have access to the shared memory of anything other than their own block.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I still don't understand is that in above example (if I use 64 threads, then blockDim.x is 32) I use 32 blocks of 64 to write 2048 ints to a shared memory. Will this "instance" of shared memory be created 32 times so every block will have it's own 2048 array? How am I doing that if I only used 2048 threads alltogether to basically copy 32*2048 ints?

Comment: @user3338991: I don't understand your comment at all. If you have a 1D thread block with 64 threads, then blockDim.x will be 64. And every block gets its own, independent shared memory allocation which is only accessible by other threads within the same block.

Comment: If I need to copy 2048 int and have 1D thread block with 64 threads, then I need  blockDim.x 32 ? (2048/64=32).
"every block gets its own, independent shared memory allocation which is only accessible by other threads within the same block." - So I will basically have 32 blocks and all of them will have it's own 2048 large array in it's independent shared memory, thus alltogether there will be 32 shared memories with 2048 ints. How is that possible if I copied only 32*64=2048 times and I end up with 32*2048 in 32 shared memories? Seems I misunderstand some basic principle.